# Loading of packages via renv stopping (for ggtree installation?)

Tags: r, package, renv, r-environment

I encountered a problem when initializing the `renv` environment with an already existing `renv.lock` file.

Starting the installation with `renv::init()` installs the first packages without problems. Then, always at the same position, after/while installation of the `ggtree` package I get a fatal error leading to the R session to abort.

I have never seen the subsequent error message before:

> *** buffer overflow detected ***: terminated
> [13097:13097:20240124,174659.828353:ERROR process_memory_range.cc:86] read out of range [13097:13097:20240124,174659.828461:ERROR elf_image_reader.cc:558] missing nul-terminator [13097:13097:20240124,174659.828633:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found [13097:13097:20240124,174659.832610:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found  [13097:13097:20240124,174659.832755:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found   [13097:13097:20240124,174659.832878:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found  [13097:13097:20240124,174659.833010:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found  [13097:13097:20240124,174659.833155:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found  [13097:13097:20240124,174659.833290:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found  [13097:13097:20240124,174659.834376:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found  [13097:13097:20240124,174659.834499:ERROR elf_dynamic_array_reader.h:61] tag not found  [13097:13097:20240124,174659.846062:ERROR directory_reader_posix.cc:42] opendir: no such file or directory (2)

NOTE: Installing `ggtree` outside of `renv` works without errors:

```
# Install and load renv (if not already installed)
if (!require("renv", quietly = TRUE, lib.loc = "~/R-4.3.2/library")) {
  install.packages("renv", lib = "~/R-4.3.2/library")
}

library(renv, lib.loc = "~/R-4.3.2/library")

# Initialize and restore the renv environment
renv::init(force = T)
renv::restore()
```

[see console output](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MY0dH.png)